# Unable to display images on Flutter app when using Scaffold Class

Tags: flutter

I am writing code for a simple flutter app.
The code is very simple,

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          shadowColor: Colors.black38,
          title: Text(
            'Some Ramdom Text',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Image.asset('images/poor.png'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

However when I run it, I get the below error:

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/poor.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

What could I be missing? I tried refactoring the project.

I checked the pubspec.yaml, it looks good.

```
  assets:
  - images/
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error states itself `It was not able to find the assets or load it` do a pub get in pubsec.yaml after saving it.
It will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio, and when I open pubspec.yaml, I see the option Pub Get on the right top corner on the screen.

This enables the project to install the referenced packages.

After this I was able to view the image.